# Calling super class' async method from async method in extending class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, ecmascript-2017, testcafe

I'm writing JavaScript (> ECMAScript 6) and I can't figure how to call a super class' async method in an extending class' method.
This is what I'm trying to do:

```
class SuperClass {
    constructor(){}

    async method() {
        return;
    }
}

class ExtendClass extends SuperClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    async method() {
        return super.method();
    }
}
```

The above won't compile, getting this as error:

```
SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here
    at Object.<anonymous> (Path/To/File.js:line:character)
```

Am I actually trying to do something that isn't possible? Can't seem to Google anything useful..

It does not help to await the call to the super class, it does not help to have different method names - the only thing that helps is making the extending class' method non-async.

Comment: it works fine in mine

Comment: which version of node are you using?

Comment: v8.9.4 - I am however using a testing framework called TestCafe; it's using ECMAScript >= 6, so it should behave as wanted.. hmm.

Comment: its a syntax error right.so the version not supporting this feature.i think you should compile to es5 and run

Comment: But it is possible to compile it without the two async keywords. `super` is not the problem, even though that's what it says.

Comment: It should work as expected. Even if the problem is real, it's specific to your environment, while the question implies that it isn't so.

Comment: Does that testing framework do any kind of transpilation?

Comment: Ya, it must do some kind of transpilation, I believe. I will take this to their forum instead.

Comment: The error is likely possible if it was compiled to ES6, because in this case async methods will be transformed and `super` will appear in wrong place. I guess changing compilation target to ES5 would solve that.

Comment: I think you are right. I can't seem to change compilation target, though.

Comment: I'd expect it's possible to edit Testcafe config file to force `es2015` Babel preset somehow, this would result in ES5 output. Yes, this is a question for Testcafe repo issues.

Comment: Yes, this sounds likely. I will look for such a file, but the documentation of this library is not so rich as of yet - I will try their forum.
Thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the transpilation used in the testing framework, TestCafe (as stated by @Bergi). I will direct the question elsewhere. Thanks for the comments.

**UPDATE**

This is currently a bug in the TestCafe framework ([link to bug](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3930)).
The workaround is as follows:

```
async method () {
    return await SuperClass.prototype.method.call(this)
}
```